# Possible inaccuracy in Wikipedia article about initial ordinals

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, axiom-of-choice, ordinals

I quote from the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_cardinal_assignment):

"So (assuming the axiom of choice) we identify $\omega_\alpha$  with $\aleph_\alpha$, except that the notation $\aleph_\alpha$ is used for writing cardinals, and $\omega_\alpha$ for writing ordinals. "

Let's remind ourselves of the definitions:

**(Def.1)** The $\aleph_\alpha$ numbers are defined recursively, with $\aleph_0 = |\mathbb N| = \omega = \omega_0$ and $\aleph_{\alpha + 1} =$ the least ordinal such that it has strictly greater cardinality than $\aleph_\alpha$ for $\alpha \in \mathbf{ON}$.

**(Def.2)** The initial ordinal of a cardinal $\kappa$ is defined to be the least ordinal of cardinality $\kappa$. Then $\omega_\alpha$ are the [transfinite initial ordinals](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InitialOrdinal.html).

Then by definition, every $\aleph$ is an ordinal and also by definition, $\aleph_\alpha = \omega_\alpha$, with or without AC. What am I missing? Thanks for clarification.

Comment: It is perhaps good to add a link to [current revision](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Von_Neumann_cardinal_assignment&oldid=439050771) of the Wikipedia article - it might change (or be totally removed).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps they're alluding to the fact that without the axiom of choice, not all infinite cardinals are alephs; with it, the finite ordinals and the $\aleph_\alpha$ take care of all the cardinals.

Comment: 18 seconds... :-)

Comment: Just to confirm: you are saying we don't need AC to get $\aleph_\alpha = \omega_\alpha$?

Comment: You're correct about that, Matt.

Answer (score 3):

The $\aleph$ numbers are *defined* as the initial ordinals, without any appeal to the axiom of choice. This is done by a transfinite recursion over the ordinals. $\aleph_\alpha$ is therefore the ordinal $\omega_\alpha$, which is the unique initial ordinal such that the set of all initial ordinals strictly smaller than itself has order type $\alpha$.

In some places define cardinals *only* as $\aleph$ numbers, and then you need AC to assert that every set has a cardinal number. Of course you can do it without AC but then there are non-$\aleph$ cardinals as well.

---

One should note that before Dana Scott suggested the definition of a cardinal without the axiom of choice much later than von Neumann suggested using the $\aleph$ numbers. Historically, if so, it was "obvious" how to assign cardinals when the axiom of choice was present, but not without it.

Comment: That's not what I asked. The passage is saying that we need AC to make the identification $\aleph_\alpha = \omega_\alpha$ and my question is, do we? (Note that this identification is _not_ the definition of $\aleph_\alpha$).

Comment: @Matt: And if you read what I wrote *closely* you will see that I answered that in the first line of this answer.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I still don't understand how this is true.

Comment: @Matt: Actually the identification *is* the definition.

Comment: Is there a reason for unaccepting?

Comment: I had first accepted Cameron's answer, then accepted yours because after the third edit or so it did answer my question quite well. But then I thought that that's not a good reason to unaccept Cameron because he answered my question in a comment, before yours did.